# PHP Array and Switch Case Statement

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement, case

My Code wont work.
It just prints out the default

Here is the php

```
$updatesQuery = "SELECT * FROM updates WHERE Isnote = 0";
        $rs  = mysql_query($updatesQuery) or
        die("SQL: $usersQuery)<br />".mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
            switch ($i){
                case $row[CatID]=1:
                    $i = "kunder";
                    break;
                case $row[CatID]=2:
                    $i = "bokningar";
                    break;
                case $row[CatID]=3:
                    $i = "offerter";
                    break;
                case $row[CatID]=4:
                    $i = "leverantorer";
                    break;
                case $row[CatID]=5:
                    $i = "kalender";
                    break;
                default:
                    $i = "no work";
                    break;
            }
            echo $i;                
        }
```

The sql query is valid.
But my output from this is just the default value. "no work".

What have I written wrong?

Comment: what is the value of $i dude...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch on your variable, in this case `$row['CatID']`:

```
switch ($row['CatID']){
    case 1:
        $i = "kunder";
        break;
    case 2:
        $i = "bokningar";
        break;
    ...
```

Comment: This is what the poster was almost certainly trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `$i` is never set, so the `switch()` statement defaults to the (surprisingly) default clause.

Change your code to something like this;

```
        switch ($row['CatID']){
            case 1:
                $yourVar = "kunder";
                break;
        }
```

A switch statement looks at a current variable. If that variable happens to be a column from a database, you need to evaluate *that* particular variable.

Your code would have worked if you had assigned your variable `$i` the data inside `$row['catID']` before the switch.

Comment: +1 And I assume that the OP has a bad understanding of how a `switch` works. `$row[CatID]=1` is a variable assignment that doesn't make much sense…

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess

```
switch ($row['CatID']) {
  case 1:
    $i = "kunder";
    break;
  // And so on
}
```

- `$i` is never defined
- `$row[CatID]` should trigger a notice, because you forgot the `'`
- `$row[CatID]=2` sets the value, which doesn't make much sense in context

Answer (score 0):

```
switch($row['CatID'])
```

Then use case 1:, case 2: etc